# How to assign an IP address to a dynamic node in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have created a dynamic node successfully, but the Ipv4Configurator did not assign an IP address to this new node. How can I assign an IP address to the wlan interface of this node?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at examples/adhoc/hostautoconf. That example deals exactly with your problem. The `HostAutoConfigurator` module states:

> HostAutoConfigurator automatically assigns IP addresses and sets up
>   routing table. It has to be added into each host.
>
> This configurator is deprecated. Please use IPv4NetworkConfigurator
>   whenever it is possible. This module is **kept only because the
>   IPv4NetworkConfigurator cannot assign IP addresses to modules that are
>   dynamically created/destroyed**.

Comment: As a side note, adding the extra module to the host requires you to subclass the WirelessHost node type as the example shows. This might be a bit annoying. It would be great to be able to replace the 'configurator' submodule in the IpV4NetworkLayer module, so switching to manual configuration could be done only by modifiyaning an INI file. I will add this to the INET issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was trying to apply your suggestion. But I got another error: 
No such interface 'wlan' -- in module (inet::HostAutoConfigurator)

Comment: probably the interface is called 'wlan0' ? You should specify that for the configuration module's interfaces parameter.